# Google's OAuth Consent Screen doesn't allow users to reject requested scopes?

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace

Originally, I believe the OAuth consent screen would allow the user to uncheck certain scopes they didn't want the requesting app to have access to (ie. [the user could decide not to give the app permission to use phone_number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSzRU.png)). Google would then send user on their way to the App with whatever access scopes the user consented to. If the app absolutely required that permission then it would be the responsibility of the app to inform the user of this.

Now (I'm not sure when this changed) it seems the user is no longer given the option to deselect a requested scope. [They can only allow it or be stuck on the consent screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drHJe.png)

Is this appropriate behavior according to the OAuth spec? To me it shouldn't be the responsibility of the resource owner to halt consent entirely due to the user denying a certain requested scope. This seems to be a Google bug, correct?

To be clear, I am working to make my app only request the scopes it absolutely requires. But I don't think that this change should be absolutely necessary.